# storing some application values in kubernetes etcd?

Tags: database, kubernetes, etcd

I have application that have some user settings and it runs on kubernetes cluster.
I would like the user settings to survive application crash/pod restart.

I was thinking first about having a DB instance for keeping it outside of kubernetes. Then I thought, maybe I could just abuse etcd to store small amount of custom data.
Is it a good approach to keep things simple?

Another options I see:

1. separate db instance outside of kubernetes(overkill)
2. some json file on PV volume in kubernetes being constantly re-read.
3. perhaps use hashicorp vault?

What would you use? Its very small amount of data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `Persistent Volume` and `Persistent Volume claim`. `pvc` or `Persistent Volume claim` will keep data incase of pod restart or pod crash.  this the best way i think to store user data. you can have the suitable storage type and resource size as per your requirement. you can look into official doc. [Ref](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-persistent-volume-storage/#create-a-persistentvolumeclaim)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use etcd, a Kubernetes built-in database, it's not really suited for this purpose and shouldn't be used in practice. App shouldn't know about Kubernetes. You need to use DB or PVC to store app related objects in a disk (for example json, yaml or other files).

Comment: thanks, sounds reasonable enough. It just feels like kubernetes is lacking support for some stateful features... That would be ugly hack, with the etcd.

Answer (score 1):

[ConfigMaps](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/configmap/) are designed to store application config/data persistently and allow you to mount the data into one or more application Pods.
There are multiple ways they can be mounted, one common way is via environmental variables.
Here is an example from the docs:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: dapi-test-pod
spec:
  containers:
    - name: test-container
      image: k8s.gcr.io/busybox
      command: [ "/bin/sh", "-c", "env" ]
      env:
        # Define the environment variable
        - name: SPECIAL_LEVEL_KEY
          valueFrom:
            configMapKeyRef:
              # The ConfigMap containing the value you want to assign to SPECIAL_LEVEL_KEY
              name: special-config
              # Specify the key associated with the value
              key: special.how
  restartPolicy: Never
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use etcd, however it's likely overkill for the requirements you outlined above. If you are sure you want to store stateful information in k8s, I'd suggest mounting a persistent volume to your deployment and then using a filestore such as BoltDB (https://github.com/boltdb/bolt) to interface with it.

That being said, I think running a simple SQL database outside of k8s is the simplest overall solution. Anything stateful is never simple with kubernetes and this way you can easily administer the database.

Comment: DB outside of k8s is probably the easiest, but still it feels silly to have separate host with separate DB just for one table with 100 records. I think I will go for PVC and python tinyDB...